# How to dynamically change the value of a CSS property inside a stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, css, class

If I have css:

```
.myclass
{
background: #FF00FF;
}
```

And html:

```
<div class="myclass">etc.</div>
<div class="myotherclass">etc.</div>
<div class="myclass">etc.</div>
```

How can I change the background variable of myclass to another color, so that all div's of that class get their background changed?

no jquery please, thanks

Comment: The background variable?

Comment: CSS does not have variables, guess you mean classname.

Comment: Do you think that changing property in the style sheet is going to be applied to that element other than onload event? Once the page gets completely loaded and if you change the property in style sheet, does it affects the elements in the page?

Comment: @AmGates It does. See the demo in my answer.

Comment: @Šime Vidas I asked will it work other than onload event

Comment: @AmGates Sure, why wouldn't it? If it works on the `onload` event, it also works on any other event - the `onload` event is not special in any way. For instance, after a timeout: http://jsfiddle.net/gHXbq/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
[].every.call( document.styleSheets, function ( sheet ) {
    return [].every.call( sheet.cssRules, function ( rule ) {
        if ( rule.selectorText === '.myclass' ) {
            rule.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/gHXbq/

*[ES5-shim for IE8](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)*

Comment: I have thousands of div's but only a few need to be change, so this sort of thing is to slow. I don't see any way around adding a id to every div, oh well.

Comment: @Myforwik What do you mean? I'm not iterating the DIV element's, but the style sheets. The performance of my code is not dependent on how many DIV's there are on the page.

Comment: Oops i meant to say I have thousands of classes, with usually about 2 or 3 divs using each class.

Comment: @Myforwik An you need to change the background of potentially any of those thousand classes? So you have several thousand different colors?

Answer (score 0):

Hope I am close to what you are expecting when I say You may please try something like this:-

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("div").toggleClass("myclass");
    });
});
```

```css
.myclass
    {
       background: #FF00FF;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<button>Set the color property of all p elements</button>

<div class="myclass">etc.</div>
<div class="myotherclass">etc.</div>
<div class="myclass">etc.</div>



</body>
</html>
```