# css class attribute changing in dynamically

Tags: php, javascript, css, attributes, codeigniter-2

I have a codeignter based site.In that i loaded the css file like this:

```
<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

This is the content in that file:

```
.forgot_password {
    color:#FF0000;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-left:95px;
    margin-top:10px;
    display:none;
}
.forgot_message {
    display:none;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#C4ED10;
}

.enter_password_fr {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Then i want to check `forgot_password` this class exist in the css file.If it exists then i want to chnage the color attribute of the this (`forgot_password`) class.Can i do this using php?

How can i change the attribute?Is this possible by any way?

Comment: You could read the CSS file into PHP, check for the class. Manually overwriting is possible in the html's head->style section.

Comment: I think your approach is a bit misguided. You may want to set the class forgot_password in the html element, if you check on a variable sent to the view, not if the class exists in the css file.
Anyhow it is better not to have a dynamic stylesheet as you would have to prevent the browser from caching the css file, which is not a good practice.

Comment: @djot :: how can i do this b converting to php

Comment: As far as I know there (yet) does not exist any implementation of `CSSOM` for PHP which would be the way to go IMHO. Until it does not exists, you would need to create your own parser and CSS manupulation library.

Comment: https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it with the help of the Javascript and there is the possible duplicate of your question please [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797546/how-to-dynamically-change-the-value-of-a-css-property-inside-a-stylesheet)

Hope this helps

Comment: but in this .myclass { background: red; } is still have red not yellow you changed.I also change that into the css file .

Comment: It will not change in the css file it will be getting applied to the element which has the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you dynamically add a second style to the element that would override the color?

```
.forgot_password_alt {color:#f00 !important;}
```